# Can not add role with dot (.) in the name via Geoserver REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

ran into a funny problem.
While adding new role in geoserver Via REST Api asks to send the role name in URL itself https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/roles.yaml , which essentially makes it difficult to create role name with dot (.) in it . like comp.admin